# cobra command Flag value manipulation

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra, pflag-go

I want to validate my `int64` flag to make sure that its not being recognised as a octal number (the value must not start with `0`, if it does, I should be able to trim the leading `0` before assigning the value to the flag).

This is how I create the command:

```
var jobId int64

func newGetJobCmd() *cobra.Command {
    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "job",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            //some processing code here that accesses `job-id` flag value
            return nil
        },
    }

    flagSet := cmd.PersistentFlags()
    flagSet.Int64Var(&jobId, "job-id", 0, "Job Id.")

    return cmd
}
```

This `job` is a sub command to `get` command and its used like this:
`my-cli get job --job-id 065`
Expectation: the code is expecting `jobId` to be 65, but because golang treats numbers leading with `0` to be octal, jobId when accessed in the code comes as 53 (which is the octal representation of 65).
I want to be able to somehow validate the input vale of `job-id` flag and trim the leading zeros before it's accessed in the `RunE` function.

**workaround**:
I have made `jobId` as string and bind it like this: `flagSet.StringVar(&jobId, "job-id", 0, "Job Id.")`, then later in my code I trim the leading zeros and parse it to an `int64`. But this is not ideal because the `command.Help()` help message now documents `job-id` flag as a string, which is misleading because in reality it is supposed to be an `int64`